# Google Map with iframe

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show Google Map in WordPress Website using Elementor. I am using this iframe `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1lpxvIAeOhsxqMqQ2GrFNzonnDCmZe6o&ehbc=2E312F&z=17&hl=en" width="640" height="480"></iframe>`. But I am getting a Black Top bar as like this image.

[image]

How can I remove the Black Top bar ? Actually I am not getting `Google API Key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're embedding a `Google My Maps` map (probably to specifically pin your location), so you don't actually need an API key, but it has that limitation of putting that bar with the title of the map.

To work around it you have two options:

### Option 1

When using **Elementor's free version**, and when you don't use any addons that include a Google Maps widget, use the `HTML Widget` that's included with Elementor, and embed your map like so:

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<iframe style="position:relative; top:-67px;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1lpxvIAeOhsxqMqQ2GrFNzonnDCmZe6o&ehbc=2E312F&z=17&hl=en" width="640" height="480">
</iframe>
</div>
```

**Why does this works?**

You're placing your iframe within a div tag that has `overflow:hidden` css attribute, meaning that whatever "overflows" this div will be automatically hidden.

The iframe has `position:relative; top:-67px;` css attributes which places the embed -67 pixels from the top of the iframe, causing it to overflow the div, hiding the bar.

### Option 2 (tidier)

By searching for the address on Google Maps you can select to share it, and get the embed code, without having the bar, as this is Google Maps, and not Google My Maps:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3651.0616209302098!2d90.41976748458553!3d23.78081993257394!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3755c796d245d8b7%3A0xeef970e7b9b7ff7e!2sMini%20Plaza%2C%20Ga%20-%2093%20Gulshan%20Badda%20Link%20Rd%2C%20Dhaka%201212%2C%20Bangladesh!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sil!4v1693302232785!5m2!1sen!2sil" width="640" height="480" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

Google's instructions for sharing the embed are [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

[image: Your address in a Google Maps embed]

Either way, you won't have your business name on the map, but you can always add it as a header above the `HTML widget` or add your place to Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks @erutan. How can I show my business name on the map ?

Comment: @abuabu here is [Google Maps guide](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) on how to add your business and verify it, so it appears on the map.